# Error trying to "Install" ngx-bootstrap "version": "2.0.0-beta.9"

Tags: installation, ngx-bootstrap

Newbie here having issues trying to "Install" ngx-bootstrap "version": "2.0.0-beta.9" on Mac 10.13.1 (High Sierra) using NetBeans 8.2 with node v 8.7.0 and npm v 5.4.2.

ngx-bootstrap: "version": "2.0.0-beta.9

Angular: 4.3.0 || >5.0.0

Bootstrap:  "bootstrap": "3.3.7",

Build system: Angular CLI

Not sure how to upgrade deprecated versions listed below. These are not found in the package.json file.
Seems my environment may need adjusting. Help appreciated!

I get the following errors after doing an "Install" :

> "/bin/bash" "-lc" "\"/usr/local/bin/npm\" \"install\""
>   npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
>   npm WARN deprecated chalk@2.0.1: Please upgrade to Chalk 2.1.0 - template literals in this version (2.0.1) are quite buggy.
>   npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
>   npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
>   npm ERR! Error while executing:
>   npm ERR!   /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/valorkin/markdown-loader.git
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! exited with error code: 1
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR! /Users/xxx/.npm/_logs/2017-11-25T13_19_26_323Z-debug.log
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with macOS.

You could first list the [outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) packages with

```
npm outdated
```

and then [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) the outdated modules with

```
npm update package_name --save
```

the `--save` option store the version in package.conf.

Otherwise, if nothing helps, you can go the hard way. You remove the node_modules directory and install the node_modules again with

```
npm install
```

that install all modules that are listed in package.conf and their dependencies, see [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Another fine node module that probably can help you ist [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) which automatically checks for updates if you run it.

Comment: I still have a no go situation with this problem. Appreciate the one response but was not able to use this to solve the problem.

Comment: I still have a no go situation with this problem. Appreciate the one response but was not able to use this to solve the problem. With previous versions I was able to, at least, do an "Install" with NetBeans 2.0 and Node.js and npm before having an error with the "Start". (Note that when I use a Terminal window for the npm commands I get the same errors) I'm thinking my environment could have issues but not sure. It seems many people are using the ngx-bootstrap-development app with success so it must be possible to build. Any other comments appreciated.

Comment: I use ngx-bootstrap 2.0.0-beta.9 for instance. Show your package.json please and the output of npm outdated.